# Id with HMBT association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

trying to do a billing application, i have 4 models customer, particular, bill and billpart
customer is registered user, and can have many bills, bill can have many existing particulars only, my models as below

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :ph_no

  validates :name, :ph_no, :presence => true

  has_many :bills
end


class Particular < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :part_name, :part_qty

  validates :part_name, :presence => true

  has_many :billparts
  has_many :bills, :through => :billparts
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :billdisc, :customer_id

  validates :billdisc, :customer_id, :presence => true

  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :billparts
  has_many :particulars, :through => :billparts
end


class Billpart < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bill_id, :part_amt, :particular_id

  belongs_to :bill
  belongs_to :particular

end
```

**my billing controller**

```
def new
    @bill = Bill.new(customer_id: params[:customer_id])

    #billpart
      @all_billparts = Billpart.all

      @billpart = Billpart.new

      @all_particulars = Particular.all 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bill }
    end
  end
```

**my new billing view**

```
<%= form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
  <% if @bill.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@bill.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this bill from being 
 saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @bill.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :customer_id %>
  </div>

<%= form_for(@billpart) do |f| %>
  <% if @billpart.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@billpart.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this billpart  
from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @billpart.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bill_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :bill_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :particular_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :particular_id, @all_particulars, :id, :part_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :part_amt %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :part_amt %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add more" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :billdisc %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :billdisc %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with the above code when try to generate new bill will not have any bill_id and how will billpart get a bill_id to associate with

Answer (score 0):

solve the issue by understanding 
Nested Model Form (revised)
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised, which was a great help